# Enabling the PHP readfile function in Virtual Host or .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, virtualhost

Is is possible to enable the php readfile function within .htaccess or within the virtual host, the functionality has been disabled by the sys admin who does not want to enable it. I need to enable it for a specific directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he explicitly disabled it in the **`php.ini`**, you can not re-enable it in other places, of course.

BTW, even if you'd find a way to do it ... if I would be your sysadmin I will discover the trick soon and I'll remove your account at all!

My hint is, find a hosting giving you this opportunity !

Comment: Found another solution, I used file_get_contents was nt disabled. Thx